# Convert a string into array of strings

Tags: postgresql

In a postgresql query, I would like to turn a given string, split it by comma, and return the results as an array of strings.

Input:

```
'a,b,c'
```

Expected output:

```
{'a','b','c'}
```

Using `STRING_TO_ARRAY('a,b,c')` yields the result `{a,b,c}` which is an array of objects, not strings.

How can I achieve array of strings?

Comment: `{a,b,c}` **is** an array of strings. The default text representation of an array simply doesn't include the quotes around each element if they are not needed. https://dbfiddle.uk/ieZxwUIz